# Getting same probability values for running the same code many times in prediction of images

Tags: python

I tried in keras (using tenserflow backend) to classify and to predict the multi-class images. i built the model with accuracy 98 % and validation accuracy was 96 %. I predicted the probability of image classes and i got the probability values. When i am trying to predict the images with existing model (already built) i got different probability values for every run of predict code. kindly help me out to solve this issue.

```
generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'image_multi_classes/predict_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=1,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=False)
```

Comment: what model are you using? if it is a neural network, this could be because the weights are being randomly set every time you rerun the code

Comment: I used CNN. I run the code for model building one time only but I run the code for prediction using the model more than one time. For every time i am getting different probability values. this is my code for prediction              
    prob = classifier.predict_generator(generator, steps=10) # to predict 10 new images

Comment: interesting, please paste your code or at least a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)